# How do you scraping sites with DOM manipulation when loading sites

Tags: dom, web, web-scraping, phantomjs, data-manipulation

Usually I have code snippets on what I'm working on, but this time I'm having trouble finding anything technologies for this.

What is the best way to web scrape sites that have a form to submit and then results page using dynamic DOM manipulation like adding div containers, updating data values using technology like angularjs or react.

Good example sites are southwest airlines or Booking.com.

I tried nightmare and phantoms, but they both seem to not work well on the wait and then retrieve.

Anyone have any technology suggestions or sites that explain what to do well?

Comment: Why didn't phantom work? all it does is mimic user interaction.. if a user can do it.. then phantom can do it

Comment: maybe you want to try something like https://pptr.dev/